# How to find the Euler Lagrange Equation of this energy function?

Tags: calculus

I come across this problem: Find the Euler Lagrange Equation of this energy function
\begin{equation*}
J(u) = \int_{0}^{1} c(x) \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}u(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^{2} \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
So $\frac{\mathrm{d}J(u + tv)}{\mathrm{d}t}$ at $t = 0$ would be $2 \int_{0}^{1} c(x) \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}u(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}v(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right) \mathrm{d}x$. However, without the differentiability of $c(x)$, I cannot do the integration by part, choose $v(x)$ that is compactly supported inside $(0,1)$ and obtain the differential equation. Do you think that it is just the problem forgot to mention the differentiability of $c(x)$, or it is in fact not necessary?

Comment: Calling $L = c u^2'$ we have $L_u-(L_{u'})_x = -2(c'u'+c u'')=0$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to look at it that'll get you started. The Lagrangian $L=cu^{\prime 2}$ gives Euler-Lagrange equations $u^{\prime 2}=0,\,(2cu^\prime)^\prime=0$, which simplifies to $u^\prime=0$ regardless of $c$. In particular, on-shell $cu^\prime$ is differentiable because it's identically $0$.